# Building ffplay with CMake

Tags: c++, linux, build, cmake

I tried to build ffplay, using the description of the following library: [electron-ffplay](https://github.com/stevevista/electron-ffplay), but on a Linux system.

Specifically, I tried to build with:

```
cmake . -DFFMPEG_SRC_DIR=/FFmpeg
cmake --build .
```

but all I got is the following error:

```
[6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ff_binding-linux-x64.abi-83.dir/src/win_delay_load_hook.cc.o
c++: error: /ignore:4090: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ff_binding-linux-x64.abi-83.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/ff_binding-linux-x64.abi-83.dir/src/win_delay_load_hook.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/ff_binding-linux-x64.abi-83.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

[Edit: I use that library because I need to run FFplay with electron]

Comment: Well, do you have the needed library installed? Do you have the development packages for it installed?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded FFMPEG lib and gave the path to cmake

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the questions in my comment...

Comment: hmmmm sorry, can you explain which tools do you mean? (I've cmake,gcc..)

Comment: I mean; do you have both the runtime library installed as well as the development components (like header files)..? And do you have your compiler set up to find the headers and the linker to find the library files?

Comment: Probably not, is there any automatic way to get them?

Comment: "is there any automatic way to get them?" - Usually your distributions package manager has an easy way to install both `lib` and `lib-devel` packages.

Comment: Ok thanks, after ignoring line160 i requested to install libsdl2 (which i installed using apt-get). Now I got various compliation errors like: /usr/include/pthread.h:775:9: error: ‘clockid_t’ has not been declared
  775 |         clockid_t __clockid,
      |         ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:921:12: error: ‘clockid_t’ has not been declared
  921 |            clockid_t __clockid,
      |            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:943:12: error: ‘clockid_t’ has not been declared
  943 |            clockid_t __clockid,
      |            ^~~~~~~~~

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you've encountered another error (as hinted in my response), which is likely due to the fact that this repository was written to run on Windows, not Linux. You should put such error messages in a **question post**, not in comments, as they cannot be easily viewed in the comments section. Because this error appears to be unrelated to that in your initial question, you may get the best help by asking a [New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). However, the responses might be the same as mine: this repository was written for Windows, not Linux.

Comment: Because this repository seemed relatively quiet, your best bet might be to contact the repository maintainer, and open an [issue](https://github.com/stevevista/electron-ffplay/issues) against the repository. Or, simply try building this repository on Windows instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Line 160](https://github.com/stevevista/electron-ffplay/blob/db5b3c3488f7ad5e0347113f95565ae578856d58/node-ffplay/CMakeLists.txt#L160) in the CMake code in this repository has the line:

```
set_target_properties(${_TARGET} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/ignore:4090")
```

which looks like it was intended to disable MSVC compiler warning [4090](https://learn.microsoft.com/gl-es/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4090?view=vs-2019). Unfortunately, Visual Studio does not recognize the `/ignore` compile flag, nor does your Linux-based compiler. You can simply comment out this line in the CMake code to get rid of that error.

FWIW, the build instructions for this repository are Windows-based, so it may **not** support building on a Linux environment. It is highly possible that you will encounter more issues trying to build this repository on Linux.